# How can I filter rows where the column lists are not equal to my list length?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list such as this:

```
MyList = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

And a dataframe such as:

```
                ColumnA      ColumnA
1       ['a', 'a', 'b']   something1 
2  ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']   something2
```

I would like to filter the df on columnA by my MyList length so only, in this case, row 1 would remain.

I tried this, but sadly it fails me:

```
df = df[df['ColumnA'].apply(lambda x: 
len(x) == len(MyList))]
```

Comment: Very close. Let me know if you're still having trouble after looking through the duplicate.

Comment: @ALollz Sadly I get a list does not have str error. Following the duplicate, this would require me to first generate the length column and filter on that.  Is it however doable in one line?

Comment: It was a dtype list at first but laod csv made it a string. But fixed it with load csv converter.